# Haystack needles intersection - find set in haystack with most elements

Tags: sql, sqlite, intersection, set-theory

I need to find out which price is valid for a feature

- A feature can have 1 or more pricerules (number of rules < 10; usually < 4)
- The price for the feature can be dependent of others features ordered
- The price can be reduced or increased depending of the other features ordered (below F2, F3).
- Some features have no influence for the price of F1 (below F6, F8, F9).

[Sqlfiddle demo with sample records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/740cf/6)

From the haystack (the order) each feature (here `F1`) must be matched to a pricerule. The valid price is the one with the most features intersection.

[image: Sample records and tables]

This picture shows the mapping between pricerules and different orders.  The price that is relevant for Feature F1 is based on the intersection between fetaures in the pricerule table and the features that are part of the order.

[image: pricerules for feature F1 and orders with feature F1]

Example

- The price for `F1` depends on the features `(F1, F2, F3)`
- The price for Feature `F1` can be determined by selecting the price rule for `F1` which has the most elements in its intersection with the haystack (the order).

This example has three pricerules for feature `F1` and three different orders.

- Order 1 has only `F1` to match against the pricerule for `F1`; the correct price is 6
- Order 2 has two matching features (`F1+F2`) in the haystack that matches pricerule for `F1`; the correct price is 4
- Order 3 has three matches (`F1+F2+F3`) for `F1`; the correct price is 2

This query is a is my attempt to join the records but many duplicates and wrong join records are present

```
SELECT op.OrderId, op.Id as OrderPositionId, 
       op.FeatureId, f.Featurename, pr.Price 
FROM OrderPositions op 
INNER JOIN FeatureCombinations fc ON op.FeatureId = fc.FeatureId
INNER JOIN Features f on op.FeatureId = f.Id
INNER JOIN PriceRules pr ON fc.PriceRuleId = pr.Id
ORDER BY op.OrderId, op.Id, f.Id;
```

[Sqlfiddle demo with sample records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/740cf/6)

From the current result all records with (x) are wrong

| OrderId | OrderPositionId | FeatureId | Featurename | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 211 | 1 | F1 | 6 |
| 401 | 211 x | 1 | F1 | 4 |
| 401 | 211 x | 1 | F1 | 2 |
| 402 | 221 x | 1 | F1 | 6 |
| 402 | 221 | 1 | F1 | 4 |
| 402 | 221 x | 1 | F1 | 2 |
| 402 | 222 x | 2 | F2 | 4 |
| 402 | 222 x | 2 | F2 | 2 |
| 403 | 231 x | 1 | F1 | 6 |
| 403 | 231 x | 1 | F1 | 4 |
| 403 | 231 | 1 | F1 | 2 |
| 403 | 232 x | 2 | F2 | 4 |
| 403 | 232 x | 2 | F2 | 2 |
| 403 | 233 x | 3 | F3 | 2 |

### Question

How to determine which pricerule for a feature matches best (`elements from order ∩ elements from pricerule`)?

#### SQL Statemens to create the tables with records

Create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Features(
  Id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Featurename  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE PriceRules(
  Id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Price  REAL   
);
CREATE TABLE FeaturesPriceRules(
  FeatureId   INTEGER, 
  PriceRuleId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(PriceRuleId) REFERENCES PriceRules(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE FeatureCombinations(
  PriceRuleId INTEGER,
  FeatureId   INTEGER,   
  FOREIGN KEY(PriceRuleId) REFERENCES PriceRules(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id)  
);

CREATE TABLE OrderPositions(
  Id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, 
  OrderId   INTEGER,   
  FeatureId   INTEGER,     
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id)  
);
```

Create records

```
INSERT INTO Features (Id, Featurename)
VALUES (1, 'F1'), (2, 'F2'), (3, 'F3'),
       (4, 'F6'), (5, 'F7'), (6, 'F9'),
       (7, 'E1'), (8, 'ZA2');

INSERT INTO PriceRules (Id, Price)
VALUES (101, '6.00'), (102, '4.00'), (103, '2.00'),
       (105, '24.00'), (106, '22.00');  
    
INSERT INTO FeaturesPriceRules (FeatureId, PriceRuleId)
VALUES (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103),(7, 105),(7, 106);  
               
INSERT INTO FeatureCombinations (PriceRuleId, FeatureId)
VALUES (101, 1), (102, 1), (102, 2),
       (103, 1), (103, 2),(103, 3), 
       (105, 7), (106, 7), (106, 8); 
       
INSERT INTO OrderPositions(Id, OrderId, FeatureId)
VALUES (211, 401, 1), (221, 402, 1),(222, 402, 2),
(231, 403, 1),(232, 403, 2),(233, 403, 3);
```

See also this [Sqlfiddle demo with sample records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/740cf/6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show all order positions. For this we join OrderPositions with Features. Now the only thing missing is the price that we can get in a correlated subquery:

```
select
  op.orderid,
  op.id as orderpositionid,
  op.featureid,
  f.featurename,
  (...) as price
from orderpositions op
join features f on f.id = op.featureid
order by op.orderid, op.id;
```

To get the price is a bit tricky, because we must look at all the features in the order to get the price rule that covers most features in the order. This requires an aggregation of the feature set joined with the order features per rule. All features required in the rule must be matched. The matching rules - if there is more than one - must be ranked, so we use an `ORDER BY` clause: In case of ties, we want the rule that requires most features (order by count of features in descending order), and if we still get a tie, e.g. an order with features F1, F2, F3 and two candidate rules on [F1, F2] and [F1, F3], this algorithm will pick one of them arbitrarily.

This is the subquery: We aggregate by rule and count the number of matching features in that rule. Then we order by the match count descendingly. For ties we want to get the rule that requires less matches, so we order by the total feature count, too.

```
select pr.price
from featurespricerules fpr
join PriceRules pr on pr.id = fpr.PriceRuleId
join featurecombinations fc on fc.priceruleid = pr.id
left join OrderPositions op2 on op2.orderid = op.orderid
                            and op2.featureid = fc.featureid
where fpr.featureid = op.featureid
group by pr.id
having count(op2.id) = count(*)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

The complete query:

```
select
  op.orderid,
  op.id as orderpositionid,
  op.featureid,
  f.featurename,
  (
     select pr.price
     from featurespricerules fpr
     join PriceRules pr on pr.id = fpr.PriceRuleId
     join featurecombinations fc on fc.priceruleid = pr.id
     left join OrderPositions op2 on op2.orderid = op.orderid
                                 and op2.featureid = fc.featureid
     where fpr.featureid = op.featureid
     group by pr.id
     having count(op2.id) = count(*)
     order by count(*) desc
     limit 1
  ) as price
from orderpositions op
join features f on f.id = op.featureid
order by op.orderid, op.id;
```

For your sample data I get

| OrderId | orderpositionid | FeatureId | Featurename | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 211 | 1 | F1 | 6 |
| 402 | 221 | 1 | F1 | 4 |
| 402 | 222 | 2 | F2 | (null) |
| 403 | 231 | 1 | F1 | 2 |
| 403 | 232 | 2 | F2 | (null) |
| 403 | 233 | 3 | F3 | (null) |

Your sample data doesn't contain price rules for F2 and F3, so we don't know their respective prices.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/740cf/113

#### Update

[new Fiddle URL](https://sqlfiddle.com/sqlite/online-compiler?id=c0feacb6-8c0d-4dba-8c56-b2a5b988ab8a) with filter NULL out

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I was, however, a bit quick to post it and you were a bit quick to accept it. :-) My solution included rules that required additional features that were not present in an order. I've removed these now with a``HAVING` clause. And this clause covers part of what I first had in the `ORDER BY`, so this clause becomes simpler. Sorry for the half-baked solution I posted. I actually over-complicated things a bit. Now the query should be correct.

Comment: Thank you for having worked on it even after i accepeted. Is this statement `this algorithm will pick one of them arbitrarily` still the case? What if there are multiple rules where the same feature plays a role: pricerules for A: `(A), `(A,B), `(A,X,D)`, pricerules for B: `(A), `(A,Y), `(A,Y,D)`. Here D plays a role for A and B.

Comment: As to ties: Yes, that still applies. For order 403 the best rule is #103 on F1/F2/F3. If you change this and remove F2, then you suddenly have two rules that are equally good; rule #103 on F1/F3 for 2$ and rule #102 on F1/F2 for 4$. So far the query will bick one arbitrarily. If you want to pick the highest price or the lowest price in such a situation, you'll have to add the price to the `ORDER BY` clause. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/112f3/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/112f3/2

Comment: As to other constellations: Try to understand the query completely. Then think about how the query deals with a particular case or create a small test case and see it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Note: In this query I have implemented CTEs for calculating if the Order qualifies for a Rule.

**Answer:**

```
;WITH cteFeatureCombinationsNeeded AS (
  SELECT fc.PriceRuleId, IFNULL(COUNT(fc.FeatureId), 0) countOfFeaturesNeeded
  FROM FeatureCombinations fc
  GROUP BY fc.PriceRuleId
  )   
, cteFeatureCombinationsProvided AS (
  SELECT op.OrderId, fc.PriceRuleId, fc.FeatureId,
    IFNULL(COUNT(fc.FeatureId), 0) countOfFeaturesProvided
  FROM OrderPositions op
  LEFT JOIN FeatureCombinations fc
    ON op.FeatureId = fc.FeatureId
  WHERE fc.PriceRuleId IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY op.OrderId, fc.PriceRuleId
)

SELECT op.OrderId, op.Id as OrderPositionId, op.FeatureId, 
   f.Featurename, MIN(pr.Price)     
FROM OrderPositions op
LEFT JOIN FeatureCombinations fc
  ON op.FeatureId = fc.FeatureId
LEFT JOIN cteFeatureCombinationsNeeded cfcrn
  ON cfcrn.PriceRuleId = fc.PriceRuleId
LEFT JOIN cteFeatureCombinationsProvided cfcrp
  ON cfcrp.PriceRuleId = fc.PriceRuleId
  AND cfcrp.OrderId = op.OrderId
INNER JOIN Features f
   ON f.Id = op.FeatureId
INNER JOIN PriceRules pr
   ON pr.Id = cfcrp.PriceRuleId
WHERE 
  countOfFeaturesNeeded = countOfFeaturesProvided
GROUP BY op.Id, op.FeatureId
ORDER BY op.OrderId, cfcrp.countOfFeaturesProvided, fc.FeatureId, pr.Price
```

See also this [Sqlfiddle demo with sample records](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/740cf/122)

From the current result all records:

| OrderId | OrderPositionId | FeatureId | Featurename | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 401 | 211 | 1 | F1 | 6 |
| 402 | 221 | 1 | F1 | 4 |
| 402 | 222 | 2 | F2 | 4 |
| 403 | 231 | 1 | F1 | 2 |
| 403 | 232 | 2 | F2 | 2 |
| 403 | 233 | 3 | F3 | 2 |

**SQL Statemens to create the tables with records**
Create tables

```
CREATE TABLE Features(
  Id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Featurename  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE PriceRules(
  Id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Price  REAL   
);
CREATE TABLE FeaturesPriceRules(
  FeatureId   INTEGER, 
  PriceRuleId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(PriceRuleId) REFERENCES PriceRules(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE FeatureCombinations(
  PriceRuleId INTEGER,
  FeatureId   INTEGER,   
  FOREIGN KEY(PriceRuleId) REFERENCES PriceRules(Id),
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id)  
);

CREATE TABLE OrderPositions(
  Id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, 
  OrderId   INTEGER,   
  FeatureId   INTEGER,     
  FOREIGN KEY(FeatureId) REFERENCES Features(Id)  
);
```

Create records

```
INSERT INTO Features (Id, Featurename)
VALUES (1, 'F1'), (2, 'F2'), (3, 'F3'),
       (4, 'F6'), (5, 'F7'), (6, 'F9'),
       (7, 'E1'), (8, 'ZA2');

INSERT INTO PriceRules (Id, Price)
VALUES (101, '6.00'), (102, '4.00'), (103, '2.00'),
       (105, '24.00'), (106, '22.00');  
    
INSERT INTO FeaturesPriceRules (FeatureId, PriceRuleId)
VALUES (1, 101), (1, 102), (1, 103),(7, 105),(7, 106);  
               
INSERT INTO FeatureCombinations (PriceRuleId, FeatureId)
VALUES (101, 1), (102, 1), (102, 2),
       (103, 1), (103, 2),(103, 3), 
       (105, 7), (106, 7), (106, 8); 
       
INSERT INTO OrderPositions(Id, OrderId, FeatureId)
VALUES (211, 401, 1), (221, 402, 1),(222, 402, 2),
(231, 403, 1),(232, 403, 2),(233, 403, 3);
```

Comment: The result above has incorrect rows. The `OrderPositionId = 221` + `FeatureId =1` should have a price of 4 above it is 6. The combination `OrderPositionId = 222`  and `featureId = 1` and `FeatureName = F2` does not exist; but the price for 4 for `OrderPositionId = 222` is correct.

Comment: @surfmuggle - I have corrected the answer, as per your comment.

Comment: This looks already very good. The price for every orderposition is correct: `OrderPositionId = 211 ==> price = 6`, `OrderPositionId = 221 ==> price = 4` and `OrderPositionId = 231 ==> price = 2`.  These pairs of `(FeatureId, FeatureName)` are incorrect `(1, F2), (1 ,F3) (2, F3)`. 
These tuples `(OrderPositionId, FeatureId, Price)` are all correct  `(211, 1, 6)` and  `(221, 1, 4)` and  `(231, 1, 2)` .  How can the wrong featureNames and the rows that are not relevant (OrderPositionId = 222, 232, 233) be excluded?

Comment: @surfmuggle - Featurename values corrected